# Using DictWriter to export temp dictionary to .csv

Tags: python, json, dictionary, export-to-csv

I am having an issue writing this Dictionary to a csv. I was previously using `csvwriter` but was made aware that `DictWriter` is the way to go for this. What I am aiming for is the output to look like this.

**HEADER**

`a_name|a_abbreviation|moneyline|a_pitcher|h_name|h_abbreviation|moneyline|h_pitcher|t_runs|`

**Row & Columns**

`texas rangers|TEX|+123|Mike Minor (L)|Seatle Mariners|SEA|-143|Mike Leake (R)|8.5|`

The Error below is telling me it is missing a field which is the beginning of the dictionary. I don't exactly need that if that is ok..

**Script**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import json
from lxml import html
from pprint import pprint
import re
import csv

outfile = open("BovadaOdds.csv", 'w',newline='')
fieldnames = ['abbreviation','name','moneyline','total runs','pitcher']
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

def get_data():

    url = 'https://sports.bovada.lv//baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group'
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
    html_bytes = r.text
    soup = bs4(html_bytes, 'lxml')

    # res = soup.findAll('script') # find all scripts..

    pattern = re.compile(r"swc_market_lists\s+=\s+(\{.*?\})")
    script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

    return script.text[23:]

test1 = get_data()

data = json.loads(test1)

output = {}

root = data['items'][0]

for game_line in root['itemList']['items']:
    # Create a temporary dict to store the data for this gameline
    team_data = {}


    # Get competitors
    competitors = game_line['competitors']
    for team in competitors:
        team_type = team['type'] # either HOME or AWAY
        # Create a new dict to store data for each team 
        team_data[team_type] = {}
        team_data[team_type]['abbreviation'] = team['abbreviation']
        team_data[team_type]['name'] = team['description']

    # Get MoneyLine and Total Runs
    for item in game_line['displayGroups'][0]['itemList']:
        for outcome in item['outcomes']:
            team_type = outcome['type'] # either A or H
            team_type = 'AWAY' if team_type == 'A' else 'HOME'

            if item['mainMarketType'] == 'MONEYLINE':
                team_data[team_type]['moneyline'] = outcome['price']['american']
            elif item['mainMarketType'] == 'TOTAL':
                team_data[team_type]['total runs'] = outcome['price']['handicap']

    # Get the pitchers
    team_data['HOME']['pitcher'] = game_line['opponentAName']
    team_data['AWAY']['pitcher'] = game_line['opponentBName']

    # For each gameline, add the teamdata we gathered to the output dict
    output[game_line['description']] = team_data

pprint(output)

writer.writerow(output)
```

**pprint(output):**

```
{'Chicago Cubs @ Atlanta Braves': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'CHC',
                                            'moneyline': '-130',
                                            'name': 'Chicago Cubs',
                                            'pitcher': 'Yu Darvish (R)'},
                                   'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'ATL',
                                            'moneyline': '+110',
                                            'name': 'Atlanta Braves',
                                            'pitcher': 'Mike Foltynewicz (R)',
                                            'total runs': '8.5'}},
 'Chicago White Sox @ Pittsburgh Pirates': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'CWS',
                                                     'moneyline': '+130',
                                                     'name': 'Chicago White '
                                                             'Sox',
                                                     'pitcher': 'Reynaldo '
                                                                'Lopez (R)'},
                                            'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'PIT',
                                                     'moneyline': '-150',
                                                     'name': 'Pittsburgh '
                                                             'Pirates',
                                                     'pitcher': 'Trevor '
                                                                'Williams (R)',
                                                     'total runs': '8.0'}},
 'Cincinnati Reds @ San Francisco Giants': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'CIN',
                                                     'moneyline': '+100',
                                                     'name': 'Cincinnati Reds',
                                                     'pitcher': 'Tyler Mahle '
                                                                '(R)'},
                                            'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'SF',
                                                     'moneyline': '-120',
                                                     'name': 'San Francisco '
                                                             'Giants',
                                                     'pitcher': 'Ty Blach (L)',
                                                     'total runs': '8.0'}},
 'Cleveland Indians @ Detroit Tigers': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'CLE',
                                                 'moneyline': '-130',
                                                 'name': 'Cleveland Indians',
                                                 'pitcher': 'Josh Tomlin (R)'},
                                        'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'DET',
                                                 'moneyline': '+110',
                                                 'name': 'Detroit Tigers',
                                                 'pitcher': 'Francisco Liriano '
                                                            '(L)',
                                                 'total runs': '9.5'}},
 'Colorado Rockies @ San Diego Padres': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'COL',
                                                  'moneyline': '-120',
                                                  'name': 'Colorado Rockies',
                                                  'pitcher': 'German Márquez '
                                                             '(R)'},
                                         'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'SD',
                                                  'moneyline': '+100',
                                                  'name': 'San Diego Padres',
                                                  'pitcher': 'Jordan Lyles (R)',
                                                  'total runs': '8.0'}},
 'Houston Astros @ Los Angeles Angels': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'HOU',
                                                  'moneyline': '-180',
                                                  'name': 'Houston Astros',
                                                  'pitcher': 'Gerrit Cole (R)'},
                                         'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'LAA',
                                                  'moneyline': '+155',
                                                  'name': 'Los Angeles Angels',
                                                  'pitcher': 'Jaime Barria (R)',
                                                  'total runs': '7.5'}},
 'Los Angeles Dodgers @ Miami Marlins': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'LAD',
                                                  'moneyline': '-175',
                                                  'name': 'Los Angeles Dodgers',
                                                  'pitcher': 'Alex Wood (L)'},
                                         'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'MIA',
                                                  'moneyline': '+150',
                                                  'name': 'Miami Marlins',
                                                  'pitcher': 'Wei-Yin Chen (L)',
                                                  'total runs': '8.0'}},
 'Milwaukee Brewers @ Arizona Diamondbacks': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'MIL',
                                                       'moneyline': '+142',
                                                       'name': 'Milwaukee '
                                                               'Brewers',
                                                       'pitcher': 'Jhoulys '
                                                                  'Chacin (R)'},
                                              'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'ARI',
                                                       'moneyline': '-164',
                                                       'name': 'Arizona '
                                                               'Diamondbacks',
                                                       'pitcher': 'Zack '
                                                                  'Greinke (R)',
                                                       'total runs': '8.0'}},
 'New York Yankees @ Washington Nationals': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'NYY',
                                                      'moneyline': '-120',
                                                      'name': 'New York '
                                                              'Yankees',
                                                      'pitcher': 'Masahiro '
                                                                 'Tanaka (R)'},
                                             'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'WAS',
                                                      'moneyline': '+100',
                                                      'name': 'Washington '
                                                              'Nationals',
                                                      'pitcher': 'Gio Gonzalez '
                                                                 '(L)',
                                                      'total runs': '8.5'}},
 'Oakland Athletics @ Boston Red Sox': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'OAK',
                                                 'moneyline': '+160',
                                                 'name': 'Oakland Athletics',
                                                 'pitcher': 'Daniel Mengden '
                                                            '(R)'},
                                        'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'BOS',
                                                 'moneyline': '-185',
                                                 'name': 'Boston Red Sox',
                                                 'pitcher': 'Eduardo Rodriguez '
                                                            '(L)',
                                                 'total runs': '9.5'}},
 'Philadelphia Phillies @ Baltimore Orioles': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'PHI',
                                                        'moneyline': '-125',
                                                        'name': 'Philadelphia '
                                                                'Phillies',
                                                        'pitcher': 'Nick '
                                                                   'Pivetta '
                                                                   '(R)'},
                                               'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'BAL',
                                                        'moneyline': '+105',
                                                        'name': 'Baltimore '
                                                                'Orioles',
                                                        'pitcher': 'Andrew '
                                                                   'Cashner '
                                                                   '(R)',
                                                        'total runs': '9.5'}},
 'Seattle Mariners @ Minnesota Twins': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'SEA',
                                                 'name': 'Seattle Mariners',
                                                 'pitcher': 'Wade LeBlanc (L)'},
                                        'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'MIN',
                                                 'name': 'Minnesota Twins',
                                                 'pitcher': 'Jake Odorizzi '
                                                            '(R)'}},
 'St. Louis Cardinals @ Minnesota Twins': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'STL',
                                                    'moneyline': '+102',
                                                    'name': 'St. Louis '
                                                            'Cardinals',
                                                    'pitcher': 'Jack Flaherty '
                                                               '(R)'},
                                           'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'MIN',
                                                    'moneyline': '-122',
                                                    'name': 'Minnesota Twins',
                                                    'pitcher': 'Jose Berrios '
                                                               '(R)',
                                                    'total runs': '9.0'}},
 'Tampa Bay Rays @ Kansas City Royals': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'TB',
                                                  'moneyline': '-385',
                                                  'name': 'Tampa Bay Rays',
                                                  'pitcher': 'Ryan Yarbrough '
                                                             '(L)'},
                                         'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'KC',
                                                  'moneyline': '+270',
                                                  'name': 'Kansas City Royals',
                                                  'pitcher': 'Eric Skoglund '
                                                             '(L)',
                                                  'total runs': '4.5'}},
 'Texas Rangers @ Seattle Mariners': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'TEX',
                                               'moneyline': '+123',
                                               'name': 'Texas Rangers',
                                               'pitcher': 'Mike Minor (L)'},
                                      'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'SEA',
                                               'moneyline': '-143',
                                               'name': 'Seattle Mariners',
                                               'pitcher': 'Mike Leake (R)',
                                               'total runs': '8.5'}},
 'Toronto Blue Jays @ New York Mets': {'AWAY': {'abbreviation': 'TOR',
                                                'moneyline': '+155',
                                                'name': 'Toronto Blue Jays',
                                                'pitcher': 'Jaime Garcia (L)'},
                                       'HOME': {'abbreviation': 'NYM',
                                                'moneyline': '-180',
                                                'name': 'New York Mets',
                                                'pitcher': 'Noah Syndergaard '
                                                           '(R)',
                                                'total runs': '7.5'}}}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mike/Desktop/BOVADA_Output.py", line 68, in <module>
    writer.writerow(output)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\csv.py", line 151, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Seattle Mariners @ Minnesota Twins', 'Houston Astros @ Los Angeles Angels', 'Cincinnati Reds @ San Francisco Giants', 'Chicago White Sox @ Pittsburgh Pirates', 'New York Yankees @ Washington Nationals', 'Toronto Blue Jays @ New York Mets', 'Philadelphia Phillies @ Baltimore Orioles', 'Los Angeles Dodgers @ Miami Marlins', 'Oakland Athletics @ Boston Red Sox', 'St. Louis Cardinals @ Minnesota Twins', 'Chicago Cubs @ Atlanta Braves', 'Milwaukee Brewers @ Arizona Diamondbacks', 'Texas Rangers @ Seattle Mariners', 'Colorado Rockies @ San Diego Padres', 'Cleveland Indians @ Detroit Tigers', 'Tampa Bay Rays @ Kansas City Royals'
```

Comment: @cricket_007 any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution using `DictWriter` due to getting the same `ValueError` for `fieldnames` that you posted.

However it seems possible with [csv.writer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

```
writer = csv.writer(outfile) # changed csv.DictWriter to a csv.writer 

# ... everything else unchanged ...

d = output # unnecessary use of a shorter dictionary name to use in below for-loop

for k, v in d.items():
    entry = [d[k]['AWAY']['name'], d[k]['AWAY']['abbreviation'], d[k]['AWAY']['moneyline'], d[k]['AWAY']['pitcher'], \
             d[k]['AWAY']['name'], d[k]['HOME']['abbreviation'], d[k]['HOME']['moneyline'], d[k]['HOME']['pitcher'], \
             d[k]['HOME']['total runs']]

    writer.writerow(entry)
```

produces a `csv` file with contents:

[image: csv screencapture]

Comment: Ok, so I was doing it right originally with csv.writer but not looping through it properly. Could you explain what the k and v are for in the loop? I have not seemed to grasp that yet.

Comment: There still might be a way to do it with a DictWriter, but I've no idea how it would be done. As for the `k`'s and `v`'s, they are just variable names I chose for the `keys` and `values` that get returned when iterating over the `output` dictionary (which I just named `d` for easy typing). You can see them in your code if you put `print output.items()` near the line `pprint(output)`.

Comment: For each entry in the dictionary you should get something like `u'Colorado Rockies @ San Diego Padres` for the `key` and `{u'HOME': {'abbreviation': u'SD', 'moneyline': u'-5000', 'pitcher': u'Jordan Lyles (R)', 'name': u'San Diego Padres', 'total runs': u'4.5'}, u'AWAY': {'abbreviation': u'COL', 'moneyline': u'+1200', 'pitcher': u'German M\xe1rquez (R)', 'name': u'Colorado Rockies'}}` for the `values`.

Comment: That has all the data we need for each row we write to the `CSV` file, and by indexing the dictionary with each `key` (`key` being the name of each "team", that we want its "value" for we can write it as `output[key]['AWAY']['abbreviation']` or `output[key]['HOME']['moneyline']`, etc, for all entries in the dictionary. There's probably a cleaner way to do it, but instead I just hard-coded all the strings since you knew which values you wanted to get. Sorry for the verbose explaining, I hope it's a little easier to understand, if not, comment here and I or someone can add clearer explanation.